# How can I control Google Hangouts with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, phone-call, videochat, google-hangouts

As a Python project, I would like to control Google Hangouts (start/end video/phone calls, mute/unmute, dial a key, etc) using Python 2.7; e.g. create a `call()` function that accepts email addresses and phone numbers of people in my circles/contacts and call those people.

As a newbie, however, I don't know whether:

1. There is already a Python package that does (most of) that,
2. I need to sign up for Google Cloud, install Google Cloud SDK, learn
   how to use the Google App Engine, etc. or just being logged into Google in a browser is sufficient

So, I'd appreciate if someone could sketch a brief **road map** for me.

For example, what Python packages do I need?

Comment: You could use Selenium to automate the Google login and then browse to hangouts where it could proceed to begin a chat or call.

Answer (score 5):

Hangups, a python instant messaging client for hangouts already exists and is probably worth a look. It's a terminal client, but it is also used as a back-end for several GUI applications.

https://github.com/tdryer/hangups

Comment: Hangups doesn't support video/voice calling from hangouts

Comment: Is there a way I could use that in a python script?

Comment: Is there a Windows solution to this?